# Save data in 2d dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

What would be the fastest way to store the data from a `Dictionary<string, int[][]>` and `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>` to a file, that later can be imported and converted back to the variables?

Currently, I use code like this (this is for the `Dictionary<string, int[][]>`):

```
        string saveString = "";
        int i = 0;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int[][]> entry in data)
        {
            if (i > 0)
                saveString += "|";

            saveString += entry.Key + ":";

            int j = 0;
            foreach (int[] x in entry.Value)
            {
                if (j > 0)
                    saveString += ";";

                int k = 0;
                foreach (int y in x)
                {
                    if (k > 0)
                        saveString += ",";

                    saveString += y;
                    k++;
                }
                j++;
            }

            i++;
        }

        string dir = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Config.saveDirectory, Config.saveName);

        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dir, "data.txt"), saveString);
```

And although it works, it is very slow (and doesn't look especially good either).

What would work better?

Comment: For working code you might also be interested in posting on [codereview.se]

Comment: You may also be interested in [Signs you're a bad programmer](http://www.yacoset.com/Home/signs-that-you-re-a-bad-programmer).  Section 1 item #4.  Just as a helpful note, not a personal one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not looking at the good place. The problem is **not** with *storing* the data, it's with *getting* the data.

With your example, with as low as 50 entries of `int[30][30]` (~91600 string concatenations if I looked correctly), it take up to 6600ms! No storing involved, only the concatenation part. The problem is, each time you're appending to your string, you need to start at 0 and go *all the way to the end*, wasting a lot of time.

You can read [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm) from Joel Spolsky to learn more about that phenomenon.

To fix this, simply use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it's made for these use cases. With exactly the same dataset, it speeds up the operation from 6600ms to only 6ms.

So your initial example, now with a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder saveString = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int[][]> entry in data)
{
    if (i > 0)
        saveString.Append("|");

    saveString.Append(":");

    int j = 0;
    foreach (int[] x in entry.Value)
    {
        if (j > 0)
            saveString.Append(";");

        int k = 0;
        foreach (int y in x)
        {
            if (k > 0)
                saveString.Append(",");

            saveString.Append(y);
            k++;
        }
        j++;
    }

    i++;
}

string dir = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Config.saveDirectory, Config.saveName);

if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
}

File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dir, "data.txt"), saveString.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you! It really made a difference. Now it just take a second or two, before it took over a minute!

Comment: @SnackerSWE No prob. But I encourage you to read the about the internals of how strings works and why it's bad to concatenate :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatinating string, use StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder saveString = new StringBuilder();
...
saveString.Append(...); // Instead of saveString  += ..
...
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dir, "data.txt"), saveString.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at Serialization. .NET Framework has several build-in implementations: Binary, XML, Json. Also you can try [Protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

Answer (score 0):

The [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) handles both dictionaries and jagged arrays:

```
// setting up sample data
var data = new Dictionary<string, int[][]>();
int[][] x = new int[][] {new int[]{1,2,3},new int[]{4,5,6}};
data["One"] = x;
x = new int[][] {new int[]{11,12,13},new int[]{24,25,26}};
data["Two"] = x;

// serialization starts here:
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, int[][]>));
ser.WriteObject(stream1, data);
```

the result will look like:

```
[{"Key":"One","Value":[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]},{"Key":"Two","Value":[[11,12,13],[24,25,26]]}]
```

To deserialize, just call `ReadObject`:

```
// reusing the original stream for demonstration purposes - it reality this would be a new stream
stream1.Position = 0;
var data2 = (Dictionary<string, int[][]>)ser.ReadObject(stream1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use JSON instead of inventing your own markup. And one of most popular libs for serializationa\deserialization JSON is [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)